# Futurama Group Viewing Event!

Tags: discussion, group-watching, futurama

Our last viewing event was fun, but school and work got in the way of me transcribing the event to a blog post, but in light of the TOTW this week, I'd like to suggest a group viewing event!

If we decide to go ahead, I would like to do it on Sunday 6/17/2012 (this coming Sunday) around 8pm CST (2AM 6/18/2012 UTC). You may register yourself [here](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/info/3789/group-viewing-event?tab=schedule) so you can get a reminder the day of.

If you are wanting to participate, please leave an answer here with a few choice episodes you'd like to watch and the 3 most popular (2 or 4 if time permits) will be viewed.

The only way we can guarantee everyone sees the same things is to watch the episodes on Netflix. But if people outside the US have DVDs available, we can try to accommodate.

The rules on the group chat are simple: Everyone will hit play on Netflix at the same time. The conversation must be kept to commentary on Futurama, specifically the current episode we are watching. Funny comments are encouraged, and we will be starring our favorites, which I will bold when creating the blog transcript. No foul language please as I really don't have time to censor everyone.

If all goes well, (and I don't have my classes to hold me back, which I shouldn't during the summer) I should have the blog post up in time for the Futurama site to be up and link to it.

A list of 10 "best of" episodes by i09: http://io9.com/5814694/the-10-best-futurama-episodes

Comment: This will be a separate ordeal from @keen's marathon event.

Comment: "Ordeal"?  That's not the word I'd choose for what I'm doing to myself.  "Celebration" is a better term, methinks. :D

Comment: Oh boy, that's 4 in the friggin' morning. On Monday ... Anyhow, given the flood of recent Roswell questions that episode along with one of the "Brain" ones should probably be part of this, right?

Comment: @bitmask you mean "Roswell That Ends Well"?

Comment: @OghmaOsiris: yes.

Comment: @OghmaOsiris: So, which ones are we going to watch? Any clues how to decide? Chat seems dead.

Comment: I like the three you posted. We might have to reschedule. I forgot it was fathers day.

Comment: @OghmaOsiris: I don't see what that's got to do with everything.

Comment: Me either but there's only 2 ppl in the chat lol

Comment: @OghmaOsiris: None, by my count.

Answer (score 2):

Count me in.

Any and all episodes that feature Zapp Brannigan.

Comment: Just pick a couple at random. Think back to your favorite episode and pick that one.

Comment: So be it, *jedi.*

Answer (score 2):

To make a definitive list (feel free to edit this post)

- [S01E04](http://theinfosphere.org/Love%27s_Labours_Lost_in_Space) Love's Labours Lost in Space (to make Jack happy, it's the first Zapp episode)
- [S02E06](http://theinfosphere.org/Brannigan,_Begin_Again) Brannigan, Begin Again (the quintessential Zapp Brannigan episode)
- [S03E10](http://theinfosphere.org/The_Luck_of_the_Fryrish) The Luck of the Fryrish (because I want to hear Farnsworth say his "Dirt doesn't need luck" line)
- [S04E01](http://theinfosphere.org/Roswell_that_Ends_Well) Roswell that Ends Well (because so many questions rely on its events)
- [S05E11](http://theinfosphere.org/300_Big_Boys) Three Hundred Big Boys (coffee coffee coffee coffee coffee)

Comment: Dang, this is so hard. I think every single episode is my favourite. They're all friggin' brilliant!